# Why is the "1" needed in the new search grammar?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

There are three that seem to be out of place on https://stackoverflow.com/search:

```
noanswers:1 closed:1 wiki:1
```

I suggest it would make more sense to not require the 1 (since it doesn't seem to have any semantic meaning) and reword the grammar so it was either

```
noanswers: closed: wiki:
```

or better

```
answers:no status:closed type:wiki
```

or even

```
answers:yes closed:yes type:wiki
```

(Even as synonyms would be great.  I am not a computer. yes or true is nicer than 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This got addressed when we rolled out ElasticSearch (or at least some time between 2009 and now):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I like the last suggestion better, but would suggest:

`answers:n` (where *n* is the number of answers desired)

Also, [there should be a `status:deleted` option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/can-we-get-a-list-of-our-content-thats-been-deleted)...

Answer (score 3):

I agree - *yes* and *no* seem to make more sense, as in

```
answers:no
closed:yes
wiki:no
```

Although maybe shog's suggestion would work better:

```
answers:0
answers:>5
answers:<10
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter does have meaning: for noanswer, closed, and wiki you can use 0 to get the opposite result.

Comment: Presumably because it is being compared to a boolean...which suggests that there is a *simple* query composer at work here.

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

Because the creators have spent too much time programming in C. In C, 1 means true, 0 means false.